# Why is the function called before pressing a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My program draws the fractal using `pointSize_max` and `pointSize` variables, which are entered by the user in Tkinter. The problem is that the fractal is drawn before pressing a button (as soon as the program is run), and the program does not draw the fractal when the button is pressed.

```
pointLabel = tk.Label(frame,text="minimaalne pikkus")
pointLabel.pack()
pointSize = tk.StringVar()
pointEntry = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=pointSize)
pointEntry.pack()
pointSize.set(str(10))

pointLabel_max = tk.Label(frame,text="maksimaalne pikkus")
pointLabel_max.pack()
pointSize_max = tk.StringVar()
pointEntry_max = tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=pointSize_max)
pointEntry_max.pack()
pointSize_max.set(str(30))

drawButton = tk.Button(frame, text = "Draw a fractal", command=koch(int(pointSize_max.get()), int(pointSize.get())))

# koch function draws the fractal 

drawButton.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `koch` function is called when the button is created, as part of the parameter evaluation before the `tk.Button` call. You can create a function object to call instead.

```
def koch_invoke():
    koch(int(pointSize_max.get()), int(pointSize.get()))
drawButton = tk.Button(frame, text = "Draw a fractal", command=koch_invoke)
```

Comment: Thank you! But now button does not appear.

Comment: @user2690370 that's a different question I'm afraid. Does the button appear if you leave off the `command`?

Comment: I have found the problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When your script is compiled it comes to this line and runs the function since you are calling it:

```
command=koch(int(pointSize_max.get()), int(pointSize.get()))
```

Try using a lambda to prevent this from happening:

```
command= lambda x = int(pointSize_max.get()), y = int(pointSize.get()): koch(x, y))
```